# How to properly update and filter a backing List in an Android app

Tags: android, concurrency, android-service

I have an IntentService which goes to a web service and gets data from a web service. It then turns the data into a List of objects. It stores that List in the DataStore singleton, and then fires off an Intent back to the main application to tell it that data is ready.

Later, the main application will access the list from the DataStore, and display it. It can also filter this list based on some categories the user can select. When one of these is selected, my custom ListAdapter will go through the copy of the List that it has, and selects objects that match the tag selected by the user. I believe I am doing that in a copy of the list provided by the DataStore, but I'm not so sure anymore.

Here's my problem: I select one of these filters. Then I go to hit refresh. This causes the IntentService to call DataStore.getList(), which is where the ConcurrentModificationException is triggered.

What is the proper way to actually return a list from an intent service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell what's wrong, given the amount of information you've provided.

When I write an app that downloads data from the web, I use an IntentService to download the data and store it in a content provider. In the main Activity, I use a CursorLoader to run queries against the content provider and display the data when the query finishes. To "trigger" refreshes, I do the following when the download finishes:

1. Post a notification containing an Intent that takes the user back to the Activity that displays the data. This covers the case of the Activity is in the background; users can go back to the Activity at their convenience to look at the updated data.
2. Post a broadcast Intent to the Activity using LocalBroadcastManager(). This covers the case of the Activity being in the foreground; the incoming broadcast Intent can force a new query of the content provider.